# create a Login API social login (google/facebook/email)

Tags: laravel-8

i'm trying to create a Login API social login (google/facebook/email) and check in postman using laravel.
like to create api not from login button....only api need to create..please help.

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Your question should be more detailed and explain the problem more clearly

Answer (score 0):

you can use laravel socialite package

```
composer require laravel/socialite
```

**more information in** *[Laravel Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/socialite)*